# Помогите доработать регулярное выражение с группами

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Вводится строка следующего вида:

```
Фамилия,Имя,Отчество,Год,Событие
```

Необходимо написать метод `String convert(String s)`, который преобразует входную строку в следующий вид:

```
И.О. Фамилия совершил Событие в Год году
```

Менять падеж не нужно. На данный момент есть такой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner src = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = src.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println(convert(s));
}

static String convert(String s) {
    String pattern = "(\\S+\\s)(\\S{1})\\S+\\s(\\S{1})\\S+";
    String str = s.replaceAll(pattern, "$1$2.$3.");
    return str;
}
```

Программа вводит **ФИО** *(без запятых)* и выводит **Фамилия И.О.**:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример:
Гагарин,Юрий,Алексеевич,1961,полёт в космос == Ю.А. Гагарин совершил полёт в космос в 1961 году

Пока программа вывод следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К тому же программа не работает на других языках,  можно ли как-то расширить регулярное выражение через звездочку, чтобы работала на любых символах любого алфавита?

Comment: Вы используете регулярные выражения не по назначению. Регулярки используются для разбора строк, а не для генерации. Да, можно и генерировать тоже, но проще без них тогда.

Comment: Мне нужно использовать соответствующие методы классов Pattern и Matcher (которые содержат что-то в духе replace в названии) и ссылки на захваченные группы в регулярных выражениях.

Answer (score 0):

### Решение с регулярным выражением

По-моему у вас неправильная регулярка. Она вообще ничего не парсит. Посмотрите, вот здесь всё работает:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(convert("Петров,Иван,Иванович,1961,полёт в космос"));
    System.out.println(convert("Васильев,Гоша,Степанович,1988,ограбил ларёк"));
    System.out.println(convert("Ivanov,Ivan,Ivanovich,1952,to born"));
}

static String convert(String s) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S+?),(\\S)\\S+?,(\\S)\\S+?,(\\d+),(.*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    matcher.find();

    return matcher.group(3) +
           "." +
           matcher.group(2) +
           ". " +
           matcher.group(1) +
           " совершил событие " +
           matcher.group(5) +
           " в " +
           matcher.group(4) +
           " году";
}
```

На самом деле всё просто. Первая группа: `(\\S+?)` это фамилия, причём берём её целиком. После запятой идёт группа из одной первой буквы: `(\\S)\\S+?`, а после группы, насколько видите, идут символы, чтобы заполнить слово.

Вы можете подробней ознакомиться с моим регулярным выражением по [ссылке](https://regex101.com/r/6Sh1pl/2). И посмотрите внимательней на свою регулярку по [ссылке](https://regex101.com/r/yj4ktY/1). Она очень странно работает.

### Решение при помощи split()

Решение с регулярными выражениями очень сильно переусложнено. У вас очень простые вводные: строка, разделённая запятыми *(даже без пробелов!)*. У String есть прекрасный метод split(), который разбивает строку на массив строк. Подайте в него регулярное выражение, которое будет распознавать разделитель: на выходе у вас будет массив отдельных слов.

Вот так, например:

```
static String convert(String s) {
    String[] data = s.split(","); //разбили входную строку на кусочки, отделённые запятой

    return data[2].charAt(0) + // добавляем первую букву отчества
           "." +
           data[1].charAt(0) + // букву имени
           ". " +
           data[0] +           // фамилия целиком
           " совершил событие " +
           data[4] +           // событие
           " в " +
           data[3] +           // дата
           " году";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но мне нужно использовать именно методы  классов Pattern и Matcher.

Comment: А почему выдает такую ошибку?Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 1
        at P39.convert(P39.java:13)
        at P39.main(P39.java:8)

Comment: @ИринаИванова это потому что я где-то ошибся с индексами скорее всего. Либо строка на вход подаётся не такая, как вы указали. Я не тестировал этот метод

Comment: @ИринаИванова протестировал, я указал последний индекс неправильно, там не 5, а 3.

Comment: @ИринаИванова ознакомьтесь, я обновил ответ в соответствии с решением при помощи регулярок